# How to protect a directory withing a Wordpress installation with htaccess?

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess, authentication, .htpasswd

I have a wordpress installation locatet at /root/website/ and a seperate, non-wordpress subpage at /root/website/subpage/ so I can simply access it by www.domain.com/subpage

I want to have the subpage protected with a htaccess file but I always get a internal server error (500) after entering the login details.

Isn't it possible to have two htaccess files or do I have to edit the Wordpress htaccess file to protect the subpage directory?

My Worpress installation has a htaccess in it's root directory containing:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Then I have the following htaccess in my subpage directory:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "NameHere"
AuthUserFile /root/website/subpage/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

And of course I have set up a htpasswd file using a generator online.

Comment: Where is your htpasswd?
Please check: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htpasswd.html

Comment: The htpasswd file is located in the same directory as the htaccess for my subpage. It is in /root/website/subpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to **.htaccess** file in public_html or publicDirectory:

You can set what directory do you want allowed, with example from below:

```
<Directory /root/website>
# All access controls and authentication are disabled
# in this directory
Satisfy Any
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /root/website/subpage>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "NameHere"
AuthUserFile /root/website/subpage/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
</Directory>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer AdyDev however I don't get what you want to point out. I'm not a expert in this field.

Comment: Ah now I understand what you mean. So I only have one .htaccess file in the root directory of my Wordpress installation (/root/website/). Do I also have to move the .htpasswd file to the same directory? How would I exclude the /root/website/subpage/ directory from the all access and link it to the .htpasswd file?

Comment: Add .htaccess file to protect to each directory or yo can use same file from root, with deny to each directory. I will update my answer.

Comment: You can add ErrorDocument for redirect if protect or...

ErrorDocument 401 "Unauthorized Access"
ErrorDocument 403 "Forbidden"

or with link to

ErrorDocument 401 /401.shtml
ErrorDocument 403 /403.shtml